# How do I convert date to number of days in R

Tags: r

How do I convert date to number of days, starting from the first day of the year.

How do I convert the following to the expected result below?

```
   Date               
02/01/2000         
20/02/2000         
12/12/2000         
13/01/2001
```

Below is expected result.

```
Date               NumDays  TotalDays
02/01/2000          1          1
20/02/2000          51         51
12/12/2000          346        346
13/01/2001          13         379
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow! Please read [about Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/about) and [what to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). As you will find in these two links, you should "show your work!". That is: "Questions asking for code must include attempted solutions, why they didn't work". Thanks for providing a small, dummy data set and the desired results!

Comment: Should `NumDays` be the nth day of the year, or the number of days since 1st Jan?  For example, `02/01/2000` is the 2nd day of the year, but 1 day since 1st Jan. `20/02/2000` is the 51st day of the year, but 50 days since 1st Jan.

Answer (score 17):

Here's a solution using the lubridate package:

```
library(lubridate)

x <- c("02/01/2000", "20/02/2000", "12/12/2000", "13/01/2001")
date <- dmy(x)

days <- yday(date) - 1 # so Jan 1 = day 0 
total_days <- cumsum(days)
```

Answer (score 11):

Load your dataset

```
df <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(1L, 4L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("02/01/2000", 
"12/12/2000", "13/01/2001", "20/02/2000"), class = "factor"), 
    Date2 = structure(c(10958, 11007, 11303, 11335), class = "Date"), 
    NumDays = structure(c(1, 50, 346, 378), units = "days", class = "difftime")), .Names = c("Date", 
"Date2", "NumDays"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Format dates:

```
startdate <- as.Date("01/01/2000","%d/%m/%Y")
df$Date2 <-  as.Date(df$Date,"%d/%m/%Y")
```

Use `difftime` to calculate the difference in days

```
df$NumDays  <- difftime(df$Date2,startdate ,units="days")

df

         Date      Date2  NumDays
# 1 02/01/2000 2000-01-02   1 days
# 2 20/02/2000 2000-02-20  50 days
# 3 12/12/2000 2000-12-12 346 days
# 4 13/01/2001 2001-01-13 378 days
```

Comment: This should be the top answer because it's simple and only uses the standard library.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you wish to count January 1 of the year as 0 we get:

```
DF <- data.frame(Date = c("02/01/2000", "20/02/2000", "12/12/2000", "13/01/2001"))
DF$Date <- as.Date(DF$Date, "%d/%m/%Y")

Diff <- function(x, start) as.numeric(x - as.Date(cut(start, "year")))
transform(DF, NumDays = Diff(Date, Date), TotalDays = Diff(Date, Date[1]))
```

which gives;

```
        Date NumDays TotalDays
1 2000-01-02       1         1
2 2000-02-20      50        50
3 2000-12-12     346       346
4 2001-01-13      12       378
```

If you want to count January 1st as 1 then add 1 to the expression in `Diff`.

UPDATE: Correction.

UPDATE: Added `DF`definition to make it self contained.

UPDATE: We add a run using data in comment below.

```
> DF <- data.frame(Date = as.Date(c("1980-01-03", "1980-01-04", "1980-01-05", 
+ "1980-01-07", "1980-01-10", "1980-01-16")))
> 
> Diff <- function(x, start) as.numeric(x - as.Date(cut(start, "year")))
> transform(DF, NumDays = Diff(Date, Date), TotalDays = Diff(Date, Date[1]))
        Date NumDays TotalDays
1 1980-01-03       2         2
2 1980-01-04       3         3
3 1980-01-05       4         4
4 1980-01-07       6         6
5 1980-01-10       9         9
6 1980-01-16      15        15
```

Comment: @G.Grothendieck it works but the values are larger than expected . below are the result i got X_data  NumDays TotalDays
1    1980-01-03   172800    172800
2    1980-01-04   259200    259200
3    1980-01-05   345600    345600
4    1980-01-07   518400    518400
5    1980-01-07   518400    518400
6    1980-01-10   777600    777600
7    1980-01-10   777600    777600
8    1980-01-16  1296000   1296000

Comment: That is likely due to some difference between what you presented and what you really have.  I have shown a run in the post above and it seems to work.

Answer (score 2):

I guess this will help:

Use `as.Date()`

Example:

```
one <- as.Date(c("02/01/2000", "01/01/2000"))
```

number of days between 02/01/2000 and 02/01/2000:

```
days <- one[1] - one[2]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
startvalue <- "01/01/2000"
dt <- data.table(
datevalue <- c("13/01/2001","12/12/2000")
)
DateFormat <- "%d/%m/%Y"

dt[,datevalue := as.Date(datevalue,DateFormat)]
startvalue <- as.Date(startvalue,DateFormat)

dt[,TotalDays := datevalue - startvalue]

dt[,Jan01 := as.Date(paste0('01/01/',strftime(datevalue,'%Y')),DateFormat)]
dt[,NumDays := datevalue - Jan01]
```

Answer (score 1):

The `%j` datetime formatting flag will give you the day of the year starting at 0.

```
d <- read.table(text='Date
02/01/2000         
20/02/2000         
12/12/2000         
13/01/2001', header=TRUE)

d<-transform(d, NumDays=as.numeric(strftime(as.Date(Date, format='%d/%m/%Y'), '%j'))-1)
#         Date NumDays
# 1 02/01/2000       1
# 2 20/02/2000      50
# 3 12/12/2000     346
# 4 13/01/2001      12
```

Then to add the `TotalDays`, you can use `cumsum` with some modular arithmetic,

```
transform(d, TotalDays=cumsum(c(1, ifelse(diff(NumDays) > 0, diff(NumDays), diff(NumDays) %% 365 + 1))))
#         Date NumDays TotalDays
# 1 02/01/2000       1         1
# 2 20/02/2000      50        50
# 3 12/12/2000     346       346
# 4 13/01/2001      12       378
```

Or use this shorter alternative.

```
transform(d, TotalDays=cumsum(c(1, diff(as.Date(Date, format='%d/%m/%Y')))))
```

Comment: thanks. This works perfectly. But how do I get the Numtotal column where I don't have to restart counting in a NEW YEAR?

Comment: The new code did not produce the desired output. The first option gave   Date           DKM          TotalDays
1    01/03/1980    1.683748         1
2    01/04/1980    2.093704     86401
3    01/05/1980    1.732581    172801
4    01/07/1980    1.779754    345601
5    01/07/1980    4.612006    345601
6    01/10/1980

Comment: while the alternative code gave  Date  DKM NumDays TotalDays
1    01/03/1980    1.683748       2         1
2    01/04/1980    2.093704       3         2
3    01/05/1980    1.732581       4         3
4    01/07/1980    1.779754       6         5
5    01/07/1980    4.612006       6         6
6    01/10/1980    8.725274       9         9
7    01/10/1980    7.898975       9        10

Comment: Matthew it works fine just that the TotalDays count is less by one. guess I will sort that by adding one to the TotalDays column.  Date         DKM                     NumDays TotalDays
1    01/03/1980    1.683748       2         1
2    01/04/1980    2.093704       3         2
3    01/05/1980    1.732581       4         3
4    01/07/1980    1.779754       6         5
5    01/07/1980    4.612006       6         5
6    01/10/1980    8.725274       9         8
7    01/10/1980    7.898975       9         8
8    01/16/1980    2.208045      15        14
9    01/16/1980    1.486091      15        14

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this solution to get the number of the days :

`mydates <- as.Date(c("2007-06-22", "2004-02-13"))
days <- mydates[1] - mydates[2]
days <- as.numeric(days)
[1] 1225`